# Push a new object to an array of child objects with useState hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am trying to build an interface where you can create an activity and then add that to another object that contains an array of all of the built activity objects.  From the top level App.js I declare and use these functions

```
  const defaultActivity = {
    id: null,
    title: "",
    group: "",
    distance: 0,
    duration: 0,
    reps: 0,
    sets: 0,
    type: 1,
    weight: 0
  };
  const session = {
    date: selectedDate,
    start: null,
    end: null,
    activities: [{}]
  };
  const [activity, setActivity] = useState({});
  const [workout, setWorkout] = useState(session);

  function addActivityClick() {
    setWorkout({ ...workout, activities: [{ ...activity }] });
  }
```

and render the components with this

```
  return (
    <Grid container component="main">
      <Grid item sm={6}>
        <WorkoutBoard activity={activity} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item sm={6} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
        <ExerciseSelect
          activity={activity}
          defaultActivity={defaultActivity}
          setActivity={setActivity}
          workout={workout}
          setWorkout={setWorkout}
        />
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={2}
          alignItems="center"
          direction="row"
          style={{ margin: "auto" }}
        >
          <Grid item sm={6} align="center">
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              align="center"
              onClick={addActivityClick}
            >
              Add Activity
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sm={6} align="center">
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={viewWorkoutClick}
            >
              View Workout
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
```

I thought using the spread operator this would work but it only replaces that activity object, it does not append a new one as I was hoping.

I created a sandbox to illustrate : https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-glitter-93wum

Create and add an activity, then when you "view workout" it will console log that object.

```
 Array(1)}
date: Fri Feb 05 2021 16:43:52 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
start: null
end: null
activities: Array(1)
0: Object
name: "weights"
duration: 30
sets: 3
weights: 125
reps: 2
```

Thanks for any help on how I can push additional activities into that array instead of replacing it.

Comment: Where are you calling `setActivity` and `addActivityClick`? Please post a [MCVE] in the question itself

Comment: There is a link to the full sandbox example but I will add some more details here as well.

Comment: `setWorkout({ ...workout, activities: [ ...workout.activities, activity ] });`

Comment: Ahhh ok! Thanks @JaredSmith!!  That was what I needed!